# How to visualise atomic triangle model from the Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, electronic-band-theory

I am a complete beginner in consented matter theory and have been struggling to understand how some of the Hamiltonians are constructed.

I am looking at a simple example given in this [book](https://topocondmat.org/w0_background/band_structures.html#:%7E:text=Bloch%E2%80%99s%20theorem%20is%20the%20key%20to%20understanding%20electrons,a%20finite%20group%20of%20orbitals%20called%20the%20unit-cell.), where auther states that the Hamiltonian of three atoms with electron hopping between three orbitals is
$$H=-t(|0⟩⟨1|+|1⟩⟨2|+|2⟩⟨0|)+\text{h.c.}\,.$$
I am confused whether the author is thinking of three atoms with three available orbitals that can be filled with a free electron (figure 1) or three atoms with different orbitals to be filled with a free electron(figure 2)? or maybe I completely misunderstood everything?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: It's the picture on the right. More generally, you'll need to include more orbitals per atom if there is more than one valence electron.

Comment: Thank you @march !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right side of the picture is correct. The Hamiltonian you wrote is the tight-binding model. If you want to understand how the Hamiltonian is formulated, I highly recommend chapter 7 of [this book](https://books.google.co.kr/books/about/Modern_Condensed_Matter_Physics.html?id=2ESIDwAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y).

Comment: Thank you!! I'll check out the book!